# Create json object with dynamic values

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to create a JSON object with values of list of check boxes.

The key attribute of the object should be the checkbox id, i am getting it like this.

```
var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
```

This is my complete code.

```
var ImportParameters = [];
        $('#divImportOptions .ace').each(function (index, obj) {
            debugger;
            var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
            var elementValue = $(this).is(':checked');
            ImportParameters.push({ elementId : elementValue });                
        });
```

My output currently is like this.

```
{elementId: true}
```

My Required output is like this

```
{ chkAllowDetailsInfo : true}
```

What should i do in order to get the desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create an array from a collection of jQuery objects. To use a variable as the key of an object, wrap it in braces, `[]`:

```js
var importParameters = $('#divImportOptions .ace').map(function() {
  return { [this.id]: this.checked };                
}).get();

console.log(importParameters);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divImportOptions">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo" class="ace" value="A" checked="true" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar" class="ace" value="B" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="fizz" class="ace" value="C" checked= "true" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="buzz" class="ace" value="D" />
</div>
```